# Does the First Amendment protect foreign government entity?

Tags: first-amendment

Does a foreign government agency or its subsidiary, particularly on U.S. territory, have the First Amendment right?

Comment: Which first amendment right(s) do you mean?

Comment: Government agencies don't typically have "subsidiaries"; subsidiaries are typically private corporations.  More generally, foreign governments don't _need_ first amendment rights because they are immune from US jurisdiction; the US can neither restrict their speech nor prevent them from parking in front of a fire hydrant.  Can you give an example of the kind of entity you're actually interested in?

Comment: @phoog: I am asking about foreign government agency operating on U.S. territory where the US does have jurisdiction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am asking about foreign government agency operating on U.S. territory where the US does have jurisdiction.

Foreign government agencies are generally immune from US jurisdiction in the US under the Vienna Convention on Diplomatic Relations.  As such, they cannot be prosecuted for any crime nor sued for any civil violation unless the foreign government agrees to waive the immunity.

However, if a foreign government agency says anything that the US doesn't like, the US can expel the foreign government agency, or any subset of its officers, or even the entire diplomatic and consular delegation of that country.  They can do this regardless of where the disliked statement was made, because under the convention a host country can expel diplomats for any reason or for no reason at all.  In its most extreme manifestation, this is called "breaking off diplomatic relations" or similar.

The reaction of the US government to unpopular speech by a foreign government is therefore a political and diplomatic matter, not a legal one, and it is not particularly affected by the provision "Congress shall make no law abridging the freedom of speech."

Answer (score 2):

It does not, as I understand what you mean. in  [Agency for International Development v. Alliance for Open Society International, Inc. II](https://www.supremecourt.gov/opinions/19pdf/19-177_b97c.pdf), the Supreme Court held that "plaintiffs’ foreign affiliates possess no First Amendment
rights". Specifically

> Two bedrock legal principles lead to this conclusion. As a mat- ter of
> American constitutional law, foreign citizens outside U. S. territory
> do not possess rights under the U. S. Constitution.  And as a matter
> of American corporate law, separately incorporated organizations are
> separate legal units with distinct legal rights and obligations....it is long settled as a matter of American constitu-
> tional law that foreign citizens outside U. S. territory do not
> possess rights under the U. S. Constitution.

Thus a First Amendment argument against a law prohibiting funds being given to a foreign entity would fail (it did fail in that instance).

On the other hand, if you mean, can the US government suppress speech by a foreign person **in** the US, it cannot, not even if they are government agents.

Comment: This applies to foreign citizens outside U.S. territory. I am asking about foreign government agency on U.S. territory.

Comment: I wonder if the [FARA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_Agents_Registration_Act) could be considered a restraint on speech by foreign agents?

Comment: That case decided that a foreign affiliate of a U.S. corporation did not have those rights. The question, in part, is asking  the converse - if a U.S. affiliate of a foreign entity has rights under the bill of rights. By the logic of that case corporations are separate entities from their affiliates so the answer might be yes.

Comment: So, what you’re saying is where the US has the power, it can’t, and where it can’t exercise power, it can - except it can’t because it has no power.

Comment: @feetwet: Yes, that would be part of the question.